# iOS 7: Audio only plays in Safari, not Web App

Tags: audio, ios7, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm trying to build an iOS Webapp that uses audio. While it has been a very fickle endeavor, I finally managed to get it to work in Safari Mobile (interestingly enough it worked in chrome mobile a long time before, I don't know why…). Yet when I save it as a webapp on the home screen, the audio stops working mysteriously…

Here is the audio code. `window.helpers.gong`is a base64 encoded mp3 file.

I checked the console output in the webapp via the desktop safari, yet there are no errors thrown.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

```
window.helpers.audio = {
  myAudioContext: null,
  mySource: null,
  myBuffer: null,
  init: function() {
    if ('AudioContext' in window) {
      this.myAudioContext = new AudioContext();
    } else if ('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
      this.myAudioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
    } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support yet Web Audio API');
    }

    var self = this;

    var load = (function (url) {

      var arrayBuff = window.helpers.Base64Binary.decodeArrayBuffer(window.helpers.gong);

      self.myAudioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuff, function(audioData) {

        self.myBuffer = audioData;

      });

    }());
  },
  play: function() {
    this.mySource = this.myAudioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.mySource.buffer = this.myBuffer;
    this.mySource.connect(this.myAudioContext.destination);

    if ('AudioContext' in window) {
      this.mySource.start(0);
    } else if ('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
      this.mySource.noteOn(0);
    }
  }
};
```

The code is called like this on load:

```
window.helpers.audio.init();
```

And later it is triggered through user action:

```
...
$('#canvas').click(function() {
  if(this.playing == false) {
    window.helpers.audio.play();
  }
}.bind(this));
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch, the answer was blindingly simple:

**I had the mute switch on the side of the iPhone set to mute the whole time.**

So it turns out that safari plays audio even when the switch is on mute, yet when you save it as a web app, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the audio works on desktop Safari, and not on mobile Safari?

This could be a result of a limitation placed on mobile Safari that requires any sound that is played to be a triggered in a user action (for example, a click).

Read more here:
http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.com/2012/04/state-of-html5-audio-in-mobile-safari.html

Comment: No, I might have not been precise enough. It works on mobile safari, but it stops working as soon as I save it to the home screen as a web app. The init function is called when the page is loaded, the play function is called on click.